# Giving List the same type as the class which contains it

Tags: java, generics

Let's assume I have a class A that can be extended. Within that Class A I have a List `List<A>`. So this class will contain a list with elements A. Now If I subclass this class B extends A, I want class B to have the same member `List<B>`, ie the same list but this type containing items of type B. Is this possible using generics ? I can see something like `A <T extends A>`, while declaring `List<T>`, but I don't like as the information about the class type are already there.  Is there another better solution ? Example below:

```
public class A {
    List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
}

public class B extends A {
}
```

I want list to have the generic type of B in class B.

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you posted the code of A and B instead of describing it.

Comment: done - added the examples in the description

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put the behaviour in the super class, then you're going to have to tell the super class what type of class the subclass is. This can be done by adding a generic type to the super.

```
public class A<E> {

  protected List<E> items;

  public A() {
    this.items = new ArrayList<E>();
  }
}

public class B extends A<B> {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B();

    b.items.add(b);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is how I have it right now (with E extend A to add extra safety)- I was looking for something better than this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extends` keyword in generic.
For example:

```
public class A {

    protected List<? extends A> list;
    public A() {
        list = new ArrayList<A>();
    }

    public <T extends A> List<T> getList() {
        return (List<T>) list;
    }
    public void setList(List<A> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}


public class B extends A {

    public B() {
        list = new ArrayList<B>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.getList().add(new A());

        B b = new B();
        b.getList().add(new B());
    }
}
```

Comment: How you add element to list? If you have `?` you can add only null.

Comment: I think ajozwik is right - you can't add elements to the list

Comment: @user1032285, I updated answer, it is same as ajozwik 's answer.

Comment: -1 This is unsafe. See my comment on [ajozwik's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9994032/697449)